# How to display chart (rechart) with data from API in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

From this [API](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=plovdiv&units=metric&appid=ca148f5dc67f12aafaa56d1878bb6db2) I want to take from `list[0].main.temp, list[0].dt_txt` to `list[39].main.temp, list[39].dt_txt`

I want to get temperature and date and want to display on X axis temperature on Y axis dates.

```
import logo from './Images/logo.png';
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { Nav, Navbar, Button, Form, FormControl } from 'react-bootstrap';
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { LineChart, Line, CartesianGrid, XAxis, YAxis, Tooltip } from 'recharts';

const data = [
  { name: 'Page A', uv: 400, pv: 2400, amt: 2400 },
  { name: 'Page B', uv: 600, pv: 2600, amt: 1800 },
  { name: 'Page C', uv: 800, pv: 2800, amt: 1200 }
];
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(async (position) => {

        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var lon = position.coords.longitude;

        const url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&units=metric&appid=ca148f5dc67f12aafaa56d1878bb6db2`;
        const response = await fetch(url);
        let data = await response.json();

        this.setState(data);

        const urlForecast = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&units=metric&appid=ca148f5dc67f12aafaa56d1878bb6db2`;
        const responseForecast = await fetch(urlForecast);
        let dataForecast = await responseForecast.json();

        this.setState(dataForecast);
      });
    }

  }

render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">


        <LineChart width={600} height={300} data={data} >
          <Line type="monotone" dataKey="uv" stroke="#8884d8" />
          <CartesianGrid stroke="#ccc" strokeDasharray="5 5" />
          <XAxis dataKey="name" />
          <YAxis />
          <Tooltip />
        </LineChart>


      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

For now I have array `data` under the imported libraries and want to put inside all objects from the API `list[0].main.temp, list[0].dt_txt` to `list[39].main.temp, list[39].dt_txt` and display this data in x and y axis on the chart. Is there a way to get some example how to put my `dataForecast` from the API in the chart ?

**UPDATE**

I create a `data.js` file with static data and use like this:

```
    import weatherData from "./data";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      chartData: []
    };
  }

  formatData = (data) =>
    data.map(({ dt_txt, main }) => ({
      // date -> Can be used as dataKey for XAxis
      //Further you can format the date as per your need
      date: dt_txt,
      // temp -> Can be used as dataKey for Line
      temp: main.temp
    }));
```

My **componentDidMount()** look like this:

```
 componentDidMount() {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(async (position) => {

    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lon = position.coords.longitude;

    const url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&units=metric&appid=ca148f5dc67f12aafaa56d1878bb6db2`;
    const response = await fetch(url);
    let data = await response.json();

    this.setState(data);

    const urlForecast = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&units=metric&appid=ca148f5dc67f12aafaa56d1878bb6db2`;
    const responseForecast = await fetch(urlForecast);
    let dataForecast = await responseForecast.json();

    this.setState(dataForecast);

    const fetchData = async () => {
      // Commenting as getting error while fetching
      // But here you can have logic of fetching the data and
      //add listeners etc
       let res = await fetch(
        `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&units=metric&appid=ca148f5dc67f12aafaa56d1878bb6db2`
       );
       res = await res.json();

      //Here i'm using dummy promise to simulate the API call
      const promise = new Promise((res) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          res(weatherData);
        }, 500);
      });
       res = await promise;

      //After getting the data from the backend,
      //format it as per how the LineChart is expecting
      this.setState({
        chartData: this.formatData(res.list)
      });
    };
    fetchData();
  });
}
```

}

**How to use data from `fetchData` function on the chart ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per what I understand, you just need to format the data in such a way that the `Line` & `LineChart` components are expecting them to be.

```js
  formatData = (data) =>
    data.map(({ dt_txt, main }) => ({
      // date -> Can be used as dataKey for XAxis
      //Further you can format the date as per your need
      date: dt_txt,
      // temp -> Can be used as dataKey for Line
      temp: main.temp
    }));
```

You can call this method once after getting the data from backend and set the result in the state and provide it to the `LineChart` component.

Once after response is received you can call `formatData` and get the formatted data and set it like

```js
this.setState({
  chartData: this.formatData(res.list)
});
```

Finally, you can pass the data to `LineChart` and `Line` as

```
<LineChart width={600} height={300} data={chartData}>
  <Line type="monotone" dataKey="temp" stroke="#8884d8" />
  <CartesianGrid stroke="#ccc" strokeDasharray="5 5" />
  <XAxis dataKey="date" />
  <YAxis />
  <Tooltip />
</LineChart>
```

I have created [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/recharts-line-example-doijt?file=/src/LineChart/index.js) for the same. Please check this out if it's addressing what you are looking for.

Comment: I go to work now after 30 minutes I will check and will accept your answer. Thank you very much 

Comment: Nithish thank you very much for your example, now I update the question with worked componentDidMount.. can you tell me how to use data from fetchData function on my chart ?

Comment: Hey @BlagovestPizhev, I have added that `new Promise(....)` code just to simulate the API response from backend. You can remove from your actual implementation. And you don't have to do anything other than just calling `fetchData`, which will eventually call API and get response and set the formatted data in component `state` i.e., `chartData`. And we are passing `chartData` as prop to `LineChart`

Comment: I just replace weatherData with dataForecast in  res(weatherData); in promise and new data is here ... Thank you man and have a very good day :)